# Perl script hangs for no reason

Tags: windows, perl

So I have this small script which checks two log files for a specific line and compares the lines. 
The script is used on several different Windows Bamboo Agents. But on one it just hangs and doesn't exit. Since the script is used in bamboo the whole job hangs, when this script doesn't exit. 
When I check the computer via remote access and kill the script the job continues until it reaches the script again.

This is the script, which is started by another script.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $naluresult = 2;
my $hevcresult = 2;
my $hevcfailed = 0;

use strict;
use warnings;

#---------------------------------------------
#check for $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[1]

open( my $nalulog, "<", $ARGV[1] )
    or die "cannot open File:$!\n\n";
while (<$nalulog>) {
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\s+//g;
    if ( $_ =~ m/MD5:OK/ ) {
        $naluresult = 1;
    } else {
        if ( $_ =~ m/MD5:MISSING/ ) {
            $naluresult = 0;
        }
    }
}
close $nalulog;

#---------------------------------------------

open( my $hevclog, "<", $ARGV[0] )
    or die "cannot open File:$!\n\n";

while (<$hevclog>) {
    chomp;
    $_ =~ s/\s+//g;
    if ( $_ =~ m/MD5check:OK/ ) {
        $hevcresult = 1;
        last;
    } else {
        if ( $_ =~ m/MD5check:FAILED/ ) { $hevcfailed = 1; }
    }
    if ( $hevcfailed == 1 ) {
        #do stuff
    }
}
close $hevclog;

#---------------------------------------------

if ( $hevcresult == 2 ) {
    print("Missing MD5 status in HEVC Output");
    exit(-1);
} elsif ( $naluresult == 2 ) {
    print("Missing MD5 status in NALU Output");
    exit(-2);
} else {
    if ( $naluresult == $hevcresult ) { exit(0); }
    else {
        #different if-statements to print() to log
        exit(1);
    }
}

#---------------------EOF---------------------
```

Comment: You can't know for sure if it hangs, perhaps it is reading very large files? `$| =1;` at the top, and `print "." unless $. %1000;` inside every `while`

Comment: I can't know it for sure, that's right. But the files aren't that large. Between 300 and 2000 lines. And those should be parsed in less than 1100 minutes.

Comment: Also, carefully analyze the `#do stuff` part.

Comment: Mandatory file locks on a file?  I agree with mpapec, insert some progress messages to find out at which point it hangs. It must be one of the file I/O operations (most likely open or write).

Comment: The #do stuff part just checks for 4 more lines and sets $hevcresult to a specific number.  
Three of those if-statements: if($_ =~ m/Stringtolookfor/{$hevcresult = -1;}

Comment: @mpapec did this, still hangs in bamboo. manual run via remote access works fine.

Comment: @reinierpost did this, the script is called like this: perl script.pl input1.log input2.log 1> default.stdout 2> default.stderr both std files are empty, though.

Comment: Also `END{ print "Exited perl script\n" }`

Comment: There's nothing obvious here that I can see, so we can't check without knowing your input files. I suggest you add multiple `print` statements in different places to see where exactly the script is hanging. That's the best way to debug this kind of issue.

Comment: I agree, I don't see anything obvious in the code provided.  Is there anything in the `#do stuff` section that we can't see that could be causing it to hang up?

Comment: `if($_ =~ m/Mismatchdetected/)
  {
   $hevcresult = -1;
  }
  if($_ =~ m/MissingMD5detected/)
  {
   $hevcresult = 0;
  }
  if($_ =~ m/Unsupportedchecksumdetected/)
  {
   $hevcresult = -2;
  }`
This is exactly the #do stuff part. 
@terdon Problem with print stuff is, that I pipe the output to `default.stdout`and `default.stderr` and those files are somehow empty, but the script somehow exits with the right exit code. I think it's more of an bamboo problem or something with the agent.

Comment: I see two options. 1) Instrument the script as several commenters have suggested, or 2) Trace or manually run the script in debug mode (perl -d script name) to determine the cause of the hang.

Comment: was going to suggest using ``alarm`` to interrupt the program and find what __LINE__ it was stuck on.  But apparently MS Windows is broken and perlport says that ``alarm`` is sometimes blocked

Comment: Have you tried slurping the file in one go? That would also save you a lot of debugging output, just print before and after, and it should not take long for a 2000 char file, nor need that much memory

Answer (score 0):

If your files are just normal disk files that aren't being simultaneously written to by other processes, or locked, or anything like that, then there is nothing in the code you have here that should hang. If the files are both reasonable sizes, the code you have here should read through the files and finish.

However, if one of the files is locked, or is immensely large, or if you have other code that can get stuck in an infinite loop, that would explain why your program is hanging.